# Closed job posting on Wordpress Job Board

Tags: schema.org

How to tell Google that a job posting is closed? Is it better to remove the post? We use *Wordpress* with a job board template.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to set the `validThrough` property (set the date in the past if the job post already expired). You can remove the post entirely (but it will returns a 404) or remove the `JobPosting` schema (too work to do if you have a lot of posts).

See more [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting).

Answer (score 1):

Check what **[Google has to say about it](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting#remove-job-postings)**:

> To remove a job posting that is no longer available, follow the steps
> below: Make sure your page is removed by doing one of the following
> actions: Ensure the validThrough property is populated and in the
> past. Remove the page entirely (so that requesting it returns a 404 or
> 410 status code). Remove JobPosting structured data from the page.
> Keep Google informed by doing one of the following actions: For job
> posting URLs, we recommend using the Indexing API instead of sitemaps
> because the Indexing API prompts Googlebot to crawl your page sooner
> than removing the URL from the sitemap and pinging Google. However, we
> still recommend submitting a sitemap for coverage of your entire site.
> Use the Indexing API to request removal of a job posting URL from the
> Google Search index. If you're not using the Indexing API, submit a
> new sitemap to Google by sending a GET request to the following URL:
> http://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=location_of_sitemap For example:
> http://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
> We ingest the entire sitemap and recrawl the pages with lastmod times
> that are more recent than the last time those pages were crawled.